# Oauth2 Website verification system with nextcord

Tags: python, nextcord

I wanted to make a verification system using nextcord. When a user clicks the verify button, they get a link, which brings them to a website that uses oauth2 to authenticate them and then they're verified.

I don't really know how to do this and if it is possible in the first place.
Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.